# Piezo driver IC or 0-5V to 0-300V translator IC

Tags: transformer, integrated-circuit, high-voltage, solid-state-relay

I am new to electrical engineering applications so please excuse any lack of correct language.

I am looking for a 4 pin (2 on each side) or 8 pin 2 channel IC that translates a voltage difference on one side to a proportional high voltage difference on the other side. For example, one side goes from 0-5V difference and the opposite goes 0-400V, as controlled by the 0-5V signal.

I realize it might be a bit hard to do due to the high voltage in a small footprint, but I feel something like this must exist and I just don't know the right thing to google. It's something like a proportional relay but those are all automotive and therefore massive. Does something like this exist?

To clarify, one channel would look like this:

```
              __
[v_control]--|  |--[v_high]
      [gnd]--|__|--[v_high_proportional]
```

For context, I am running a piezo-controlled air valve and so controllable high voltages are required. We were running them off of LAA110 relays, but those are unable to ground the piezo elements (which essentially are capacitors in my understanding) and also don't allow for adjustable control of the piezo elements

Comment: As a "newbee" to EE, I advise you to not ask for a "translator IC" as that goes into the **implementation**. It is often the case that you might think you need such an IC while in reality, you need something really different. So instead, **tell us what you're trying to achieve**. Draw a schematic with all the things you have and draw a "black box" in the middle, then the EEs here can make suggestions for what should be in that box.

Comment: @regred002 We also need to know what your load is or what kind of current you need. It's also unclear why you can't have a ground, because any kind of load needs a return current path back to the source to make a complete circuit.

Comment: What are the current requirements? What accuracy is needed... Could you get away with something like an analog opto-isolator driving a BJT or FET?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A device as you describe almost certainly doesn't exist.

In particular the 300V requirement is difficult(and expensive) to meet. Most piezo actuators don't require that much.

Do you know of a large volume application? In general, ICs are only designed where there can be large sales. They cost too much to develop unless that is so.

When I had a similar problem I designed a discrete solution initially then worked with a semiconductor company to create an IC.

There are some piezo drivers being made by manufacturers such as Microchip(originally Supertex) and Analog Devices (originally LTC).

For example:

[Supertext HV254 32-Channel High Voltage Amplifier Array](https://www.futurel.bg/datasheets/4/HV254.pdf)

[Analog Devices LT3572 - Piezo driver with boost converter](https://www.analog.com/en/products/lt3572.html)

Comment: In this circumstance the range is 0-310V, see https://www.festo.com/media/pim/623/D15000100140623.PDF
It's a very unique application I assume because of the pressures involved

Answer (score 0):

I suppose I am unfamiliar with driving piezo based devices, but in general there are some small bricks that generally make DC-HVDC from XP-Emco such as the [Q12N-5](https://www.digikey.com/en/products/detail/xp-power/Q12N-5/5873630) which can take 5V and will have a linear output for 0.7V->5V inputs.  There are quite a few HV DC-DC converters that I've seen and used for Photomultiplier Tubes (PMTs) as they require relatively high voltage to produce their expected output.  This may be something like what you're looking for unless there are other specific requirements for driving piezo devices.

Answer (score 0):

Why not buy the product designed for it?

https://www.festo.com/net/en-us_us/SupportPortal/Downloads/648267/709190/Festo_VAVE-P_PSI_EN142509_202103_V01.pdf